# Как отловить изменения у <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Допустим у нас есть такой код и допустим пользователь оказался хитрым. Он вставил некий скрипт в код который изменяет значение у `select` при событии `click` :

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function(){document.querySelectorAll("select")[0].value=document.querySelectorAll("option")[2].value},false)
```

```html
<select onchange="console.log(event.target.value)">
  <option  value="Firefox Best!!!"  selected> Firefox Best!!! </option>
  <option  value="Firefox Very best!!!" > Firefox Very best!!!</option>
  <option  value="Chrome Best!!!" >Chrome Best!!!</option>
</select>
```

Теперь `selectElement.value="Chrome Best!!!"` и так как отловить изменение `value` у `select`? **Только не предлагать по таймингу.**

Comment: ну изменяет он значение, и что?

Comment: Ваш вопрос грубо говоря звучит так: "Как не позволить пользователю, на стороне пользователя сделать выбор". Какая разница изменил пользователь значение руками или с помощью скрипта?

Comment: Мне интересно существуют ли события или еще что-нибудь подобное для отлова изменений value у select. Если не знаете ответа, то не стоит комментировать риторическими вопросами "А зачем тебе это?", "Какая разница ... ?" и т.п.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, если почитать комментарии к ответам, его просто интересует, как отловить порграммное изменение значения, чтобы вызвался обработчтик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось в комментариях, вопорс сводится к тому, как сделать, чтобы событие `change` вызывалось при программном изменении значения в select'е.

Например, в следующем коде событие не возникает при нажатии кнопки:

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  console.log("Changed to: " + e.target.value)
})

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log("Button clicked: enter")
  document.querySelector("select").value = 2
  console.log("Button clicked: leave")
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=1 selected>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2>Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
</select>

<button>#2</button>
```

Решением может быть перехват присваивания при помощи сеттера свойства.

Следующий код проверен в Chrome 43 (в IE надо будет поменять способ создания события):

```js
var select = document.querySelector("select");

select.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  console.log("Changed to: " + e.target.value)
})

var original = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, 'value');

Object.defineProperty(select, 'value', {
  get: original.get,
  set(val) {
    console.log("set value: " + val)
    var old = this.value
    var res = original.set.call(this, val)
    if (old != val) this.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
    return res
  }
})

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log("Button clicked: enter")
  document.querySelector("select").value = 2
  console.log("Button clicked: leave")
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=1 selected>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2>Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
</select>

<button>#2</button>
```

Это же решение можно применить для всех select'ов:

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  console.log("Changed to: " + e.target.value)
})

var original = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, 'value');

Object.defineProperty(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, 'value', {
  get: original.get,
  set(val) {
    console.log("set value: " + val)
    var old = this.value
    var res = original.set.call(this, val)
    if (old != val) this.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
    return res
  }
})

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log("Button clicked: enter")
  document.querySelector("select").value = 2
  console.log("Button clicked: leave")
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=1 selected>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2>Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
</select>

<button>#2</button>
```

В любом случае, я бы не рекомендовал так поступать, потому что скрипты могут ожидать, что значение не изменится при присваивании. Портить стандартное поведение браузера - это, как правило, плохая идея.

Comment: У вас считается плохая практика переопределять методы у объектов? Переопределять методы это часть ООП. Еще понял что лучше следить за свойством `selectedIndex` чем за `value`. Как раз нашел документацию [Реализация HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty/Additional_examples).

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба, плохая практика - глобально портить встроенные объекты.

Answer (score 2):

Никак, пользователь вообще может даже не в скрипте это заменить а через `f12` в режиме отладки страницы, кроме того он вообще может отключить все скрипты на странице, сделать любые замены через `f12` и потом снова включить скрипты, и вы ничего не поделаете никакими "защитными" мерами.

Кроме того он может вообще получаемый от сервера html код перехватить например снифером или прокси и внедрить туда что угодно.

Есть и другие варианты, например использования эмуляции браузера, перекомпилированный браузер с дополнительным кодом или плагинами, и так далее.

В любом случае любой запрос от клиента на сервер надо валидировать, и вот это взломать уже мало реально, при учёте грамотного кода и надёжного сервера.

По сути варианта без валидации запросов на сервере в нормальном и защищённом коде быть не должно.

Comment: Дело в другом. Выдуманная ситуация с пользователем чисто гипотетическая. Я просто насмотрелся на все многообразие веб верстальщиков.  OMG, то ли костыли, то ли я не врубаюсь. Код на некоторых сайтах настолько ужасно выглядит, да и большие участки кода требуют рефакторинга. Вот жду помощи от просветленных достигнувших дзен. Как мне отловить изменение value у элемента. Пздынь, кипит голова.

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба ясно. может что-то и есть, это надо в новых версиях ECMA  script смотреть, в старых точно нет, слышал что отслеживания изменений хотели в новых версиях вводить, но подробности не знаю.

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба Посмотрите вот эту тему - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: применение Mutation Events является устаревшим. Вместо них используйте [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Пока не до конца прочитал, но думаю стоит прощупать.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо использовать `MutationObserver`.

```js
function changeElement() {
  document.getElementById("id1").value = "zzz";
}

var mo = new MutationObserver(observe);
var el = document.getElementById("id1");
var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subTree: true
};
mo.observe(el, config);

function observe() {
  alert("change");
}
```

```html
<select onchange="console.log(event.target.value)">
  <option  value="Firefox Best!!!"  selected> Firefox Best!!! </option>
  <option  value="Firefox Very best!!!" > Firefox Very best!!!</option>
  <option id="id1" value="Chrome Best!!!" >Chrome Best!!!</option>
</select>

<a href="#" onclick="changeElement(); return false;">изменить</a>
```

Документация - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Прочитал документацию к MutationObserver и он реагирует на "мутацию" так сказать на `"innerHTML"`. В вашем примере вы изменяли тег `option` и реакция была. А в моем примере скорее значение объекта/элемента (как кому удобнее называть) меняется. Мутации `HTML` кода нет и нет реакции от MutationObserver. Возможно я и ошибаюсь. Еще путаюсь в веб-разработке. Столько технологий. Кашка в голове :)

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба да, понял что вам надо, похоже такое реально не отлавливает. В вашем примере меняется состояние, но сам DOM не трогается как я понял, хотя по идее должна у `option` меняться `selected`, но такое похоже `MutationObserver ` не отлавливает.

Comment: Ваш ответ оказался правильным на поставленный вопрос. Но пример оказался исключением. Пока буду ждать может можно как-то в `JS`  поставить событие на изменение объекта.

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба Сюда смотрите - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe то есть это есть, но в новой спецификации ECMA script 7

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба поддержки браузерами пока почти нет

Comment: вы правы то что нужно, остается ждать выхода в свет ECMA script 7

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба тогда я оформлю в ответ

Comment: @АлексТвояТруба, ES7 - это ES2016 и он вышел 2 года назад...

Answer (score 1):

Эта функциональность есть, но она находится в экспериментальной части на данный момент ECMAScript 7

```
Object.observe(obj, callback)
```

в вашем случае это должно работать так

```
var sel = document.getElementById("select1");
Object.observe(sel , () => console.log("changed"));
```

Документация -
 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

На данный момент эта функциональность почти не поддерживается браузерами.

Comment: Надеюсь его не исключат из стандарта. В Gecko есть реализация `Object.prototype.watch()` [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch). На данный момент такой код    `document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].watch('value', function(){console.log(this.value)})`     работает но выдает предупреждение 'Object.prototype.watch and unwatch are very slow, non-standard, and deprecated; use a getter/setter instead'

Comment: Эм.. Вообще-то `Object.observe` вообще не в стандарте, [был реализован в Chrome 36 и удалён в Chrome 50](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-observe) в связи с исключением из черновика стандарта. А ES7 - это ES2016, который уже давно принят и [реализован](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/).

Comment: Если что, вместо него в ES6 есть Proxy, но к этому вопросу он не относится.

Comment: Вот документация [Ecma-262 PDF](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). Нужно будет прочитать на досуге.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего помоему через jquery))

```
<select class="status">
         <option  value="Firefox Best!!!"  selected> Firefox Best!!! </option>
         <option  value="Firefox Very best!!!" > Firefox Very best!!!</option>
         <option  value="Chrome Best!!!" >Chrome Best!!!</option>
</select>

$(function() {
   $('.status').change(function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
   });
});
```