# Почему не срабатывает else?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не срабатывает else, в чём моя ошибка?

```js
jQuery(function($){
        var ddl = document.getElementById("select");
        var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == "UA")
        {
        $("#tel").mask("+38(999) 999-9999");
        }else{
            $("#tel").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");
        }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" integrity="sha256-+4KHeBj6I8jAKAU8xXRMXXlH+sqCvVCoK5GAFkmb+2I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <select name="select" id="select">
        <option value="UA" selected>UA</option>
        <option value="RU">RU</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="tel">
```

Comment: Ваш код срабатывает единожды, но больше вы его и не вызываете.

Comment: как можно повторить вызов? делать обработку при клике на select?

Comment: Конечно: вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать когда захочется - будь то при загрузке странице или изменении значения в выпадающем списке.

Comment: @РустамГимранов вызывать когда захочется, это просто сделать вызов func() ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767431/256824

Comment: тут можно повесить событие на change

Comment: @StrangerintheQ подскажите как это сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете код один раз, только при загрузке страницы

Необходимо так же повесить событие на `change`

```js
jQuery(function($){

    setFormat()
    $('select').on('change', setFormat)
    
});

function setFormat(){
    // Ваш старый код
    var ddl = document.getElementById("select");
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "UA") {
        $("#tel").mask("+38(999) 999-9999");
    } else {
        $("#tel").mask("+7(999) 999-9999");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" integrity="sha256-+4KHeBj6I8jAKAU8xXRMXXlH+sqCvVCoK5GAFkmb+2I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="UA" selected>UA</option>
    <option value="RU">RU</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="tel">
```